# keep track on a previous value in reduce

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a array of model year of cars, so model year is the unique key here and if it exists it should only add to the totalMilage.

I know how to do this with year as identifier for year array, but in this specific situation I only want a regular identifier `[0, 1, 2]`.

here is what I'm trying to do and what I started

```js
const data = [{
    year: 2001,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  },
  {
    year: 2010,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 3,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2019,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2005,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2009,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2002,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 4,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2001,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 3,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2001,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }
]

const newList = data.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
  // try to keep track of previous year, previourYear below
  // create one array for unique years and add the milage to total
  // create array with this structure

  // if (previousYear !== cur.year) {
  //  acc = {
  //    year: cur.year,
  //    totalMilage: 0
  //  }
  // }



  return acc
}, [])
```

here is how I do with "named" array

```js
const data = [{
    year: 2001,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5
  },
  {
    year: 2010,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 3,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2019,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2005,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2009,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2002,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 4,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2001,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 3,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2001,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }
]

let newList = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const key = currentValue.year

  if (accumulator[key] === undefined) {
    accumulator[key] = {
      year: key,
      totalMilage: 0
    }
  }
  
  accumulator[key].totalMilage += accumulator[key].totalMilage + currentValue.milage
  
  return accumulator
}, [])
```

Comment: Your code snippets have errors. Would you be able to update them so that they run?

Comment: Why the first entry has no milage? What is the expected output for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some adjustments to your second attempt: the start value of the accumulator should not be an array. Also, in your question you write you want to group by year model, so the `car` property should also play a role in the grouping. Use `Object.values` to extract the grouped results as an array. And probably it would be nice to have the output array sorted by model and year...

```js
const data = [{year: 2001,car: 'Audi',nrOfDoors: 5, milage: 2000},{year: 2010,car: 'Audi',nrOfDoors: 3,milage: 2000}, {year: 2019,car: 'Audi',nrOfDoors: 5,milage: 2000}, {year: 2005,car: 'Audi',nrOfDoors: 5,milage: 2000}, {year: 2009,car: 'Audi',nrOfDoors: 5,milage: 2000}, {year: 2002,car: 'Audi',nrOfDoors: 4,milage: 2000}, {year: 2001,car: 'Audi',nrOfDoors: 3,milage: 2000}, {year: 2001,car: 'Audi',nrOfDoors: 5,milage: 2000}]

let newList = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const yearmodel = curr.year + curr.car;
    if (acc[yearmodel] === undefined) {
        acc[yearmodel] = {
            year: curr.year,
            car: curr.car,
            milage: curr.milage || 0
        }
    } else acc[yearmodel].milage += curr.milage;
    return acc;
}, {})).sort((a, b) => a.car.localeCompare(b.car) || a.year - b.year);

console.log(newList);
```

Comment: oh the `Object.values` was the missing piece for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using objects to more easily track which years you've looked at so far. Then, you can use `Object.entries` to reduce your object back into an array if you need.

```js
const data = [{
    year: 2001,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5
  },
  {
    year: 2010,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 3,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2019,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2005,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2009,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2002,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 4,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2001,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 3,
    milage: 2000
  }, {
    year: 2001,
    car: 'Audi',
    nrOfDoors: 5,
    milage: 2000
  }
];

const summed = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if(!acc[el.year]) {
    acc[el.year] = 0;
  }
  acc[el.year] += el.milage;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(summed);

const summedArr = Object.entries(summed).reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push({ year: item[0], milage: item[1] });
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(summedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get an object with total mileage by year, this would do it:

```
const data = [
    {
        year: 2001,
        car: 'Audi',
        nrOfDoors: 5,
    },
    {
        year: 2010,
        car: 'Audi',
        nrOfDoors: 3,
        milage: 2000,
    },
    {
        year: 2019,
        car: 'Audi',
        nrOfDoors: 5,
        milage: 2000,
    },
    {
        year: 2005,
        car: 'Audi',
        nrOfDoors: 5,
        milage: 2000,
    },
    {
        year: 2009,
        car: 'Audi',
        nrOfDoors: 5,
        milage: 2000,
    },
    {
        year: 2002,
        car: 'Audi',
        nrOfDoors: 4,
        milage: 2000,
    },
    {
        year: 2001,
        car: 'Audi',
        nrOfDoors: 3,
        milage: 2000,
    },
    {
        year: 2001,
        car: 'Audi',
        nrOfDoors: 5,
        milage: 2000,
    },
];

const newList = data.reduce((acc, d) => {
    if(!acc[d.year]) {
        acc[d.year] = 0;
    }

    acc[d.year] += d.milage ? d.milage : 0;

    return acc;
}, {});
```

Basically, if the accumulator object doesn't have that year yet, just create it and set to zero. Then, add current object's mileage to our accumulator by year.